# Can S3DistCp combine .snappy.paruqet files?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, emr

Can S3DistCp merge multiple files stored as .snappy.parquet output by a Spark app into one file and have the resulting file be readable by Hive?

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to merge smaller snappy parquet files into larger snappy parquet files. 
Used 
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id {clusterID} --steps file://filename.json
and 
aws emr wait step-complete --cluster-id {clusterID} --step-id {stepID}

Command runs fine but when I try to read the merged file back using parquet-tools, read fails with java.io.EOFException.

Reached out to AWS support team. They said they have a known issue when using s3distcp on parquet files and they are working on a fix but don't have an ETA for the fix.

Comment: any update? did this ever work? did the aws support team ever get back to you?